# video background not occupying full width of div?

Tags: jquery, html, css, background, html5-video

I am using [jquery.videoBG](http://syddev.com/jquery.videoBG/demo_div.html) plugin to implement video background.

HTML:

```
  <div id="div_demo">
    <div class="videoBG">
    <video autoplay="" src="media/snow.mp4" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; top: 0px; left: 0px; min-width: 100%; width: 100%; height: 650px;loop">
    </video>
    </div>
  </div>
```

css:

```
#div_demo{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 650px;
}
```

Video styles are defined inline. Problem is that when height is applied to video its width shrinks and gets aligned in the middle.

In case i remove video height it goes out of div.

Answer (score 0):

Give the parent div a style of `position:relative;`

and make sure your style is:

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
bottom:0;
right:0;
```